# Укажите предложение где менее трёх мягких согласных

Tags: перевод, фонетика

Пожалуйста, помоги мне.

Укажите предложение где менее трёх мягких согласных.

1. Он купил тетрадь.
2. Девять часов.
3. Они жили рядом.
4. Это мой день.
5. Химия - это наука.
6. Могу кататься на коньках.
7. Хочу посмотреть дом.
8. Увидишь эту девушку.

Comment: "Пожалуйста, помоги мне." - why in singular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#6,  there's only one. A trick question to test whether you know that -ться is pronounced [цца].